# Energy of static magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

I learned that the energy density of the magnetic field is

$$\mathcal{E}=\frac{1}{2\mu_0}\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{B}$$

This can be derived by analyzing the Maxwell equation and from the procedure where the Poynting vector is derived as the energy flux. This derivation involves the whole package of Maxwell equation, namely, the electric field as well as the magnetic field.

Also, for an infinite solenoid, we know the total energy stored inside by charging it to current $I$

$$E = \frac12 LI^2 .$$

Since the magnetic field is constant in this case $B=\mu_0 n I$, and therefore for a solenoid of area $A$ of unit length $L=\frac{BnA}{I}=\mu_0n^2A$, one again obtains

$$\mathcal{E}=\frac{E}{A\cdot 1}=\frac{1}{2\mu_0}B^2 .$$
This derivation only involves static magnetic field.
However, we note this is a special case where the magnetic field is constant.

Now, in the case of electrostatics, we are able to derive the form of the energy density of the system by using essentially Coulomb's law and evaluating the work needed to move all the charge from infinity to form the distribution in question. In this context, the notion of energy of the magnetic field shall also stand regarding the static magnetic field.

My question therefore is, is it possible to derive the energy density of static magnetic field by using similar reasoning as for the case of the static electric field, employing Biot-Savart's law? Many thanks!

**Edit**: Regarding the derivations in the [link](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node84.html) provided by *Hanting Zhang* in the comment, to evaluate the energy of the magnetic field still involves the induction, and therefore electric field. In principle, is it possible to discuss the concept of energy only within the framework of the static magnetic field?

Comment: A quick search will give: http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node84.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, really appreciated!

Comment: Regarding the discussion in the link, to evaluate the energy of the magnetic field still involves the induction, and therefore electric field. In principle, is it possible to discuss the concept only within the framework of the static magnetic field?